# A person is dragging another person at constant velocity over a surface.

Tags: physics

#1 If person #2 is applying a force of 200 N determine work of the kinetic friction force.  Assume Person #1 has a mass of 70 kg.  Assume person #1 is dragged over a
distance of 5 m.
#2 Determine the work done by Person #2 (applied force) on Person #1 if Person #1 is dragged over a distance of 5 m. Again, assume Person #1 is 70 kg.
#3 Determine the net work done on Person #1 if Person #1 is dragged over a distance of 10 m.[image]

I am confused because I know that the normal force and the gravitational force do no work because they are perpendicular to the displacement. But I don't know how to answer question #1 because I feel like I need to know the value of the coefficient of kinetic energy in order to solve it and I was not given that.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The velocity along the surface is constant. That means that the acceleration is zero. From Newton's second principle, the sum of horizontal forces is zero. You have $200N\cos 30^\circ$ pulling, and you have $F_{friction}$ opposing the motion. The two forces must have the same magnitude.